# "A flashback to 2015!": How do you express this idea in French without anglicisms?

Tags: expressions, anglais

> Just seeing this unique font again! Oh my God, **a flashback to 2015**!

I assume that saying:

> Ça me ramène deux ans en arrière !

... fails to convey the *sudden* aspect denoted with the word "flashback".

Comment: The sudden aspect could be translated by something like "ça nous replonge en 2015 !". I think "replonger" is "relapse" in English.

Comment: @lemon You should write this as an answer.

Comment: @AnneAunyme, I may, but I don't think it's so contributive regarding the other answers and it is nearly covered by the answer I've already wrote.

Comment: Then you should delete it. Either it is useful and should be a question, or it isn't and should not be. Comments can be deleted anytime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach may be to keep the sentence short. For instance:

"Retour en 2015 !"

"Nous revoilà en 2015 !"

"Vision de 2015 !" / "Soudaine vision de 2015 !"

"Ramené/replongé/projeté en 2015 !"

"Soudain 2015 !" / "Retour soudain en 2015 !"

Answer (score 5):

"Me voilà projeté deux ans en arrière" pourrait mieux traduire l'effet du "flash".

Comment: Hi. What's your take on "Me voilà revivant 2015 !"?

Comment: It would convey the idea of returning back to 2015, but I feel it would imply you live the whole year all over again, and all its events - not just whatever this "unique font" is about.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe using "Ça me rappelle des souvenirs d'il y a deux ans!" expresses this more directly.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that it’s just the example you chose (and it might just be me), but I usually associate the full, sudden/abrupt notion of “flashing back” with going back more than just 2 or 3 years (unless one dropped some acid in 2015, of course),  e.g., back to an earlier decade/century/millennium/era.

With this bias of mine (and this specific example of yours) in mind, while perhaps lacking the “sudden aspect” you seek, for a “flashback” to a relatively recent time I’d suggest exploring French equivalents of the less abrupt notion of [“rewinding time”](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/rewind%20time) [cf: *Reverso*’s suggestions], such as:

> Hop! Un/e petit/e rembobinage/remontée [du/dans le temps] jusqu'en 2015 !

Answer (score 0):

Ramener, replonger, n'ont pas le caractère brutal souhaité, et sont un peu plats à mon gout.

J'ai l'impression de revenir deux ans en arrière me parait le plus français, sans l'émotion américaine mais le plus naturel, marquant une forme de déception.